# Deleting a property in the global object ( misunderstanding )

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

So i was actually reading documents about the "delete" method for deleting object properties , and i stumbled upon this "Also, you cannot delete properties of the global object, which were declared with the var keyword."

So What i did understand is : let' say you create an array:

`var testing = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];`

Then if you attempt to delete the `"test1"` property ( by the way , can i call an element of an array, which is an object, a property of the array object) , or maybe if you delete the for example : delete testing.length you won't be able? i don't know if anything from what i'm saying makes sens to you , further explanation please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then if you attempt to delete the "test1" property ( by the way , can i call an element of an array, which is an object, a property of the array object).

That array does not have a property called "test1". It has a property called `"0"` with the value `"test1"`, but it is generally not good to think of arrays as having properties at all. Arrays are technically objects, and can have properties like "test1" added to them just like a regular object, but that is almost always a bad idea:

```
var testing = ['a','b','c'];
testing.test1 = 'hello';
delete testing.test1;
```

Array elements are not properties, but they are the values of properties that are the integer index of the element:

```
var testing = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
delete testing[0];
```

Using the `delete` operator to delete an element from an array is usually not what you want to do. The above results in the array:

```
[empty, "test2", "test3"]
```

with a `length` of `3`. Usually you want to remove an element from an array using [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), or [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) or [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) if you want to repetitively remove the first of last element:

```
var testing = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
testing.splice(0,1); // Delete 1 element from position 0
// Results in ["test2", "test3"]
```

Comment: For using `Array.prototype.slice()` you should first know the `index` of the value.. Better use `Array.prototype.filter()` when you know the value you want to remove `"test1"`.. Check my answer

Comment: @YosvelQuintero `filter` doesn't remove elements from an arra; it creates a new array without modifying the existing one. It has a lot of overhead compared to splice. If you want to delete a single element you should always use splice, but you may need to use `indexOf` or `findIndex` first.

Comment: That's it: combined with `indexOf` or `findIndex` will be OK... This for cases with only one occurrence of `"test1"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `"test1"` is not a property but the value of the index 0.

When working with arrays instead of `delete` you could use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and get all elements that are different from `"test1"` in a new array:

```js
const testing = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
const result = testing.filter(item => item !== 'test1');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, you cannot delete properties of the global object, which were declared with the var keyword

The `delete` operator has no effect on variables, just properties.  Although those variables are available using, i.e `window.variable` the `delete` operator has no effect on those varaiables.

> if you attempt to delete the "test1" property

`test1` is not a property, but an element within that array.

> maybe if you delete the for example : `delete testing.length`

The array property length is a **non-configurable property**, so the operator `delete`will return false.

```js
var testing = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
console.log(delete testing.length);
```

**If you need to remove an element from an array using the operator `delete`, you need to place the index, i.e: `array[3]`:**

*the best way to "remove" an element from an array is executing a filter process, you can learn a little more about the function `Array.prototype.filter()`*

```js
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
delete trees[3];

console.log(trees);
```

**Another example of non-configurable property using the function `defineProperty`:**

```js
var Employee = {};
Object.defineProperty(Employee, 'name', {configurable: false});

console.log(delete Employee.name);
```

**You can delete configurable properties from an object as follow:**

```js
var obj = {test1: "test1", test2: "test2"};

console.log(delete obj.test1);
console.log(obj);
```

**Or, as follow:**

```js
var Employee = {};
Object.defineProperty(Employee, 'name', {configurable: true});

console.log(delete Employee.name);
console.log(Employee)
```

Comment: thanks , i did get the point here , one last thing what's the meaning of that sentence :"Also, you cannot delete properties of the global object, which were declared with the var keyword."?

Comment: The delete command has no effect on regular variables, just properties.  Although those variable are available using, i.e `window.variable` the delete operator has no effect on those varaiables.

Comment: @JonasW.  Yes, I forgot that.  Later I’ll fix that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, you cannot delete properties of the global object, which were >declared with the var keyword

Variables declared with var keyword are actually properties of `global` object. `global` object can be referred by the keyword `global` in Node. In web browsers `global` object can be referenced by `window` keyword. You can access `global` object via `globalThis` keyword in ES2020 and higher versions in any context.

```
var x= 5;
console.log(globalThis.x) // => 6 : You can access variables 
//declared in global scope via *global object*
delete x; // => false: returns false in non-strict mode, cannot
//delete a var. In strict mode it would throw a TypeError
```